# Polymer 1.x: How to fetch data using firebase-document imperatively inside a custom behavior

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymerfire

I am trying to fetch data using a dynamic, imperatively created `firebase-document` element inside a custom behavior.

I have the following code. Notice the first `console.log` correctly logs as expected. But the second never logs anything. Where am I going wrong?

my-behavior.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymerfire/polymerfire.html">
...
getUserLocalSeries: function(uid) {
  var doc = document.createElement('firebase-document');
  var path = ['users', uid, 'local'].join('/');
  doc.appName = 'app';
  doc.path = path;
  var _this = this;
  console.log('path', path); // Logs fine
  doc.addEventListener('response', function(e) {
    console.log('doc', doc.lastResponse); // Doesn't log
    _this.set('userLocalSeries', doc.lastResponse);
  });
  this.set('userLocalSeries', doc.data);
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend just using the Firebase JS SDK for this instead:

```
getUserLocalSeries: function(uid) {
  var path = ['users', uid, 'local'].join('/');
  var _this = this;
  firebase.database().ref(path).on('value', function(snap) {
    _this.set('userLocalSeries', snap.val());
  });
}
```

You can use the SDK so long as you have a `firebase-app` in your project. This example requires that you omit the `name` attribute from `firebase-app`, but you could also do e.g. `firebase.app('app').database().ref()` instead.

Comment: Extra kudos for including an example using the `name` attribute.